# Passing a string between pages in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, parameter-passing

I need to pass a simple string between two pages in Windows Phone 8. I've been searching around, trying to find the best way of doing it - but the ones i tried turned out to not work as they should - so i ask you: What is the best way to pass a simple string between two pages in Windows Phone 8. This is the method I use to navigate to the other page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/newpage.xaml", Urikind.Relative));
```

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Passing_parameters_while_navigating_between_pages_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: @Erik please do not forget to check mark which answer worked best for you so future people can find this useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a string variable, it's easiest to use a query string parameter:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/newpage.xaml?key=value", Urikind.Relative));
```

Pick it up on the target page using [`NavigationContext.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("key"))
    {
         string val = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];
         // etc ...
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** if your string contains only alphanumeric characters, then the above will work without modification.  But, if your string might have URL-reserved characters (eg, `&`, `?`), then you'll have to URL-encode them.  Use the helper methods [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for this.

To escape:

```
string encodedValue = Uri.EscapeDataString("R&R");
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/newpage.xaml?key=" + encodedValue, Urikind.Relative));
```

To unescape:

```
string encodedValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];
string val = Uri.UnescapeDataString(encodedValue);
```

Comment: i then get a ArgumentNullException

Comment: I will try to run this code as soon as possible - right now my app ran into some misbehaviour that i have to fix so that it's stable before i test ur code again

Answer (score 5):

I have to say that for simple data @McGarnagle is probably a better solution.

That said, this is also an extreamly fast and dirty way to do this. This method can also take complex objects as well.

I like using `PhoneApplicationService.State` which is a `Dictionary<String,Object>`

```
PhoneApplicationService.State.add("KeyName",YourObject);
```

Then in page two you do this

```
var yourObject = PhoneApplicationService.State["KeyName"];
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you both for answers, i cannot implement it just now - my app decided to behave weird, but i'll try as soon as possible:)

Comment: And I think this method is better if you want your data to be preserved.

Comment: @Romasz Yes, youre correct. This is a very simple way of preserving data. It makes passing complex custom objects between xaml pages very simple. Instead of having to serialize them or even worse, break them into string format and pass them over the url

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM architecture,then you can pass string after registering using Messenger.
Create a model class (say PageMessage) with a string(say message) variable.
You want to pass string from homepage.xaml to newpage.xaml,then in homepage.xaml just send the message like this

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new PageMessage{message="Hello World"});
```

In the newpage.xaml,u should register the messenger like this,

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PageMessage>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));

 private object ReceiveMessage(PageMessage action)
 {
    string receivedMessage=action.message;
    return null;
 }
```

Like this you can pass anything even navigation in MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Hy,

another solution and to create a static class with one or more properties of type string depending on what you need, it enhances the way that it is available where you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Caliburn.micro. It is really simple to set up and lets you pass parameters through views in a strongly typed manner, like this:

```
public void GotoPageTwo() {  
        navigationService.UriFor<PivotPageViewModel>()  
            .WithParam(x => x.NumberOfTabs, 5)  
            .Navigate();  
}
```

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation