# How to pass a value contains special characters between pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to pass a value like this: `Black & White` between two pages. but it has a character which gives it another meaning. how to pass that value?

```
value = "Black & White";
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/secondpage.xaml?value=" + value, UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying HttpUtility.UrlEncode method to the string.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the special character ampersand `&` with slash:

Replace This:

```
value = "Black & White";
```

With This:

```
value = "Black \& White";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/secondpage.xaml?value=" + Server.UrlEncode("Black & White"), UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should construct proper `string` URL with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`  and then construct the `Uri`

```
value = "Black & White";
string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/secondpage.xaml?value=" + url, UriKind.Relative));
```

You should encode only those part of the URL that may contain invalid characters.

For example, if you encode the `"/secondpage.xaml?value="` then it will produce a `string` as,

> %2fsecondpage.xaml%3fvalue%3d

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged with `windows-phone`, so HttpUtility is not an option (there is no System.Web).

Use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instead, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224053/463697.