# Windows Phone 7 - Passing / transferring selected data from listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am creating an app where I have obtained data from a DB Via Web service and displaying it within a listbox within my mainpage.xaml (data about different events being held e.g. EventTitle, Date etc.) At the moment I have set it up so that when an item within the list box is selected the application navigates to an "EventDetail" page which portrays only the selected data from the list.

What I need help with is taking this user selected data and taking it to the navigated page to be used. I am struggling to figure out in the simplest way; how to transfer a listbox item which has been selected by the user to the defined page to display it in a more clear way and to use this data.

Preferably I would like to display each textblock/cell (EventTitle, Date etc) in separate text blocks within the navigated page so that they can be laid out appropriately but a list box with only the selected fields data would do the job.

Here is the relevant Xaml code:

```
   <ListBox  Height="496" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,155,0,0" Name="FirstListBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" SelectionChanged="FirstListBox2_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">

                            <StackPanel Width="370">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventID}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="24" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventList}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Here is the relevant C# coding:

```
     private void FirstListBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventServiceReference1.Event myEvent = (EventServiceReference1.Event)FirstListBox2.SelectedItem;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EventPageTemp.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Please if you could help me with this problem I would very much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query-string parameter to send the selected value:

```
EventServiceReference1.Event myEvent = (EventServiceReference1.Event)FirstListBox2.SelectedItem;
int eventId = myEvent.EventID;
string url = string.Format("/EventPageTemp.xaml?eventId={0}", eventId);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
```

You can [pick up the event parameter on the target page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) using `NavigationContext.QueryString`.  Then just set the data context of your target page as needed:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int eventId;
    string eventIdStr;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("eventId", out eventIdStr) && int.TryParse(eventIdStr, out eventId))
    {
        // load event data, and set data context
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I guess you might want to save the event data temporarily, rather than re-loading it from the service on the target page.  If so, you could use isolated storage to save the event data.  So before navigating, add the data using an appropriate key:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings["event"] = myEvent;
settings["eventId"] = eventId;
```

And then pick it up in the same way:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (settings.ContainsKey("event") && (int)settings["eventId"] == eventId)
{
    var myEvent = (EventServiceReference1.Event)settings["event"];
}
```

**Edit #2**

As AndreiC points out, writing to isolated storage takes up space on the device, so you should remove any items that are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank You, I will give this a try and get back to you :)

Comment: Thank you yes, this method worked perfectly for me. It is a simple and easy method and also very effective. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @mcgarnagle this will work as well, but can't see the point of placing a selection in the application settings which are persisted in the apps storage space... lets say the user taps during the use of the app on 10 events, you store 10 events on the phone. For me this is a bit of a waste of space, unless you clear this used space somehow... Storing the entire list of events which is received from the web service in the local storage is a different story as it could be used on the next launch to show the events before the list of events is updated from the server

Comment: @AndreiC yes, fully agreed.  It was a bit lazy of me not to mention that in my answer.  I've made an edit to at least fix the problem of accumulating events in storage with no limit.  Your answer does have that advantage of not using any stroage ... but I have an extreme (irrational?) aversion to using global static variables.

Comment: Hi so the first method given worked but only for the example data that was used which was the 'eventId' data. I tried to add the rest of the data to the method and for some reason it does not seem to work however I try it. The other sets of data are not integers but are strings of text. e.g.  eventDescription and eventTime. 
when i try it usually get stuck at the end and says unhandled local variable. please help me solve this issue . thank you

Comment: @Ibrahim you're passing strings?  If so then you will need to URL-encode them, if they contain reserved characters like "&", "?", etc.

Comment: @McGarnagle Would you be able to give me an example of how I could do this please?

Comment: @Ibrahim it's easy enough, you just use `Uri.EscapeDataString` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString`.  A basic example is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20224053/1001985

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to add a public static property of type Event to your App class (name it SelectedEvent) so when the user selects an event from the ListBox you would set the:

```
App.SelectedEvent = myevent;
```

Then in the EventPageTemp.xaml.cs you would just set the DataContext of the page to your App.SelectedEvent:

```
DataContext = App.SelectedEvent;
```

In the xaml page of the EventPageTemp you would just bind the interface to the properties of your Event object.