# Passing data from a ListView to a TextBlock

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, message-passing

On my Windows Phone 8.1 RT project, I have a two-page setup, Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml. Page1.xaml has a Textblock, called **p1tbl** whose tapped event, p1tbl_Tapped, takes you to Page2.xaml. It has a list of countries (in a **listview**, and everything on that works fine. I would like to know, how can I pass the ListView selection (say a country called Denmark) to the textblock **p1tbl** (same textblock that was used to navigate to page2).

Or is there another way to resolve this, **without a combobox**? ListView is imperative as I need to make use to SemanticZoom.

Just can't seem to figure this out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to pass data between pages. It is possible of course.

**1.** You can send the data by specifying a static variable and by using it in Page2.xaml. You have to use `SelectionChanged` event of listbox. Check below for an example

Page2.xaml

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string President { get; set; }
}

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //currentItem is a variable specified in General class
    //Also in this example, i supposed you have country class that contains information about a country
    //Use Country.Name to get name of selected country
    General.currentItem = (Country)ListView.SelectedItem;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (General.currentItem != null)
        p1tbl.Text = General.currentItem.Name;
}
```

**2.** You can also send data in navigation string same with query string in web development. Here is an example below:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?country=" + ((Country)ListView.SelectedItem).Name, UriKind.Relative));
```

Do not forget to handling null state of selected item. For more information about query string (second way) take a look this question.

[Passing a string between pages in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223924/passing-a-string-between-pages-in-windows-phone-8)

If I am wrong, please someone get me correct.

Comment: That didn't work. Plus, it is an RT project. Not SilverLight. Is there a way I can use Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer? I tried but I get a "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in listview_test2.exe but was not handled in user code" error.

Comment: I did this: In the ItemClick I put this:
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localStorage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            localStorage.Values["c"] = listofallcountries.SelectedItem;

In OnNavigatedTo of Page1, I put this:
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localStorage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            p1tbl_country.Text = localStorage.Values["c"].ToString();

What could be wrong?

Comment: ItemClick is in Page2 and it is p1tbl.Text and not p1tbl_country.Text in Page1, that was typed in error, so it is 

Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localStorage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            p1tbl.Text = localStorage.Values["c"].ToString();

Comment: Did you create a collection in Country data type and gave it to listview as itemssource?

Comment: Ok, I wlil give this is an extensive try now and let you know.

Comment: please try if doesnt work `listBox.SelectedValue as Country` instead `(Country)ListView.SelectedItem` as well

Comment: Hi, i have this set up now: Instead of the TextBlock, I now have a HyperlinkButton and it's Click event takes me to Page2. In page2,  the ItemClick of the list, I have this:
var item_selection_list = ListofallCountries.SelectedItem.ToString(); Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2_country_list_plus_phone_number_extractor), item_selection_list);
So I am passing item_selection_list as a parameter to Page1, that ALSO has a textblock. How can I extract my data in item_selection_list to the textblock. Am I even doing this correctly? Thnx

Comment: I shared you a link above. Check out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223924/passing-a-string-between-pages-in-windows-phone-8